# symfony2 - PHP - undefined index - Tables join

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, entity, one-to-many

I am brand new on Symfony2 and develop my first project in which I have

- 1 entity "ejuridique" who has 1 onetomany relation with
- 1 entity "projet" who has 1 onetomany relation with
- 1 entity "photo".

**I would like to have 1 table showing for each "ejuridique" the ejuridique name and his first picture of his first project.**

But, for the moment, I get an error "undefined index:chl\websitesBundle\photo" when I call from the controller my own function with 2 cascading leftjoin.

**twig "liste.html.twig"**

```
{% for ejuridique in ejuridiques %}

            <div>
                  <div>{{ejuridique.nom}} </div>
                  <div>
                        {% for projet in ejuridique.projets %}
                             {% for photo in projet.photos %}
                                 {{photo.name}}
                             {%endfor%}
                        {%endfor%}
                  </div>
              <div>

{%endfor%}
```

**controller**

```
class websitesController extends Controller
{
    public function listeAction($page)
    {

        $em = $this                   ->getDoctrine()
                                      ->getManager();

        $ejuridiques = $em            ->getRepository('chlwebsitesBundle:Ejuridique')
                                      ->findAll();

        $projets = $em                ->getRepository('chlwebsitesBundle:Ejuridique')
                                      ->myFindAll();

        return $this->render('chlwebsitesBundle:websites:liste.html.twig', array(
        'ejuridiques'=>$ejuridiques,'projets'=>$projets));
```

**ejuridique Repository**

```
class ejuridiqueRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    public function myFindAll()
        {
            $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
                ->leftjoin('a.projets', 'pr' )
                ->leftjoin('pr.photos', 'ph' )
                ->where('pr.projetPosition = :position_pr')
                ->ANDwhere('ph.position = :position_ph')
                ->setParameters(array('position_pr'=> "1",'position_ph'=> "1"))
                ->addSelect('pr')
                ->addSelect('ph');

            return $qb->getQuery()
                  ->getResult();
        }
}
```

**My 3 entities**

ejuridique

```
class ejuridique
{

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="chl\websitesBundle\Entity\Projet", mappedBy="ejuridique")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  private $projets;
```

projet

```
class projet
{

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="chl\websitesBundle\Entity\ejuridique", inversedBy="projets")
   */
  private $ejuridique;

   /**
    * @var integer
    *
    * @ORM\Column(name="projet_position", type="integer")
    */
   private $projetPosition;

  /**
   * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="chl\websitesBundle\Entity\Photo", mappedBy="projet")
   * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
   */
  private $photos;
```

photo

```
class photo
{

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $name;

  /**
   * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="chl\websitesBundle\Entity\projet", inversedBy="photos")
   */
  private $projet;

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="position", type="integer")
     */
    private $position;

}
```

So, with all this files, I receive for the moment the error "ContectErrorException: Notice: Undefined index: chl\websitesBundle\Entity\Photo" but

- When I just call from the controller a simple "findall()" on my ejuridique repository, I get all the ejuridique with all their projects and all the pictures. Consequently, I think that everything is fine with my entities and my DB.
- Same when I call my function "myFindAll" with only 1 leftjoin between "ejuridique" and "projet" with parameters. Everything is working properly.
- It's only when I have 2 cascading leftjoin in my own function "myFindAll" that I get this error

I hope my question is clear and that I have given all the necessary informations.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a small important thing in my entities like emphasized by blacksad...

PHP class name had to start with a capital letter. So it could match with

targetEntity="chl\websitesBundle\Entity**P**rojet

targetEntity="chl\websitesBundle\Entity**P**hoto

I tried to put plasters in my controller by adding another function and an array directly on "projet"  but it only partially solved my initial mistake. The controller suggested by "kanalkyte" is good.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just change this into your controller :

```
public function listeAction($page)
{

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

    $ejuridiques = $em->getRepository('chlwebsitesBundle:Ejuridique')
                       ->myFindAll();     

    return $this->render('chlwebsitesBundle:websites:liste.html.twig', array(
    'ejuridiques' => $ejuridiques));
}
```

You only need one request to get all of these informations :) But what you did should work even if your doing extra useless stuff...

I don't know if it will change anything but usually, when I make up a query, I do it this way :

```
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')
            ->leftjoin('a.projets', 'pr' )
            ->addSelect('pr')
            ->leftjoin('pr.photos', 'ph' )
            ->addSelect('ph');
            // ...
```

Comment: you are right. It was useless stuff. But unfortunately, deleting it does not change my index error as you supposed. Even if my index seem good in my DB, I think that I have to check in this way.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing up some things (or I didn't really understood what you're trying to do :-D).

------  **1**  ---------

When you do this:

```
$projets = $em->getRepository('chlwebsitesBundle:Ejuridique')
              ->myFindAll();
```

you don't get `Projet` entities, but you get `Ejuridique` entities. The `->leftjoin()` function allow you to select (or "filter") only some specific ejuridique and `->addSelect()` function to pre-load joined enities.

------  **2**  ------

When you do this:

```
{% for projet in ejuridique.projets %}
```

after that:

```
return $this->render('chlwebsitesBundle:websites:liste.html.twig', array(
    'ejuridiques'=>$ejuridiques,'projets'=>$projets));
```

you don't access your `$projets` variable, you just get all the `Project` which are linked to the current `ejuridique`. If you want to read the content of `$projets`, you'll have to do this:

```
{% for projet in projets %}
```

(But note that this is not the solution in your case.

According to these mistakes, I would strongly suggest that you take some time to read a tutorial. As you seem to be french-speaking, I suggest this one: [Openclassrooms (ex-Site du Zéro)](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2) especially [this chapter](http://fr.openclassrooms.com/informatique/cours/developpez-votre-site-web-avec-le-framework-symfony2/recuperer-ses-entites-avec-doctrine2).

Comment: I inform you that I was able to write all these files after my third day of symfony2 especially thanks to this openclasrooms lesson that I followed. But I understand your remark. I had more or less understood that I had not to write -- array('projets'=>$projets) -- but I did it because my function 'myFindAll' showed me an index error.

Comment: So I wanted to try another thing. I recognize that it was confusing. And I confirm you that I have this index error with my function 'myFindAll' when I only use -- array('ejuridiques'=>$ejuridiques'). And I have checked my DB. All the index seem good.

Comment: Please don't see any offense in my answer. I understand you're a beginner (as I was, not so long time ago), but in my opinion you should spend more time studying the basics (for example, a PHP class name always start with a capital letter). Painfull but rewardfull investment, on the long term it will probably save your time and effort. Especially if it is a professionnal project. As you saw, the Openclassroom tuto is really good, there's really all what you need (and if not, you'll be able to find and understand other tuto once you understood what's in Openclassroom). Good luck and have fun!

Comment: I had seen in my tutorial that PHP class name had to begin with a capital letter but I had not completely integrated yet. Thanks to you, it is now fully integrated. I think that everybody has his own way to move forward with motivation. And as you say, we have fun and I hope that you will help me again in the future :-)